# How do I use multiple horizontal recyclers views in one activity efficiently?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I can use multiple recyclers views in xml and assign separate ids and populate them as I want with different adapters and so on.

But I have to create recycler view in xml and initialize in Java and populate them with respective name.

Is there some other means to do. Like with include layout using loops. Can you guyz suggest something.

Like play store has multiple horizontal scrolling layout one below the other just like that.

Comment: I would suggest making vertical `RecyclerView` with adapter, in which each item would be horizontal `RecyclerView`. Recycling pattern will ensure that only currently visible (fit in viewport) items-recyclers will be working, all other will be detached from window, thus won't consume any resources